# Member Data between date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, grouping

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 named [Membership] containing personal member data and two date fields named [member from date] and [member to date].

I need to summarise the monthly membership. A member is counted in a given month only if they are a member for that whole month.

So for example, a person with [member from date] of '2014-02-01' and [member to date] of '2015-03-01' would be counted in the month of December 2014, but would not be if the [member to date] was, say, '2014-12-25'.

I need to summarise by every month going back to January 2010 and I have thousands of members in this table. The results need to look similar to this:

```
Month      Count
Jan 2010   3230
Feb 2010   3235
Mar 2010   3232
..
Dec 2016   6279
```

I can't see how to work this because of the "only if they are a member for that whole month" rule.

Any help will be most appreciated!

Comment: why the example you gave would not be in the member of Mar.2015?

Comment: If we are for example counting the membership for December 2014 then I would filter by [Member from date] <= '2014-12-01' and [Member to date] >= '2014-12-31'. Hope that clarifies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using spt_values and a cte to generate the calendar, here is an example that counts members.

```
declare @members table (member int, start_date date, end_date date)
insert @members select 1, '2015-12-15', '2017-01-15'
insert @members select 2, '2016-01-15', '2016-12-15'
insert @members select 3, '2016-03-01', '2016-10-31'

declare @cal_from datetime = '2016-01-01';
declare @cal_to datetime = '2016-12-31';

with calendar_cte as (
    select   top (datediff(month, @cal_from, @cal_to) + 1)
             [Month] = month(dateadd(month, number, @cal_from))
           , [Year]  = year(dateadd(month, number, @cal_from))
           , [Start] = dateadd(month, number, @cal_from)
           , [End]   = dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, number + 1, @cal_from))
    from     [master].dbo.spt_values
    where    [type] = N'P'
    order by number
)
select [Month]
     , [Year]
     , [Count] = (select count(*) 
                  from   @members 
                  where  start_date <= [Start] 
                         and end_date >= [End])
from   calendar_cte
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a Months table, this can be handled pretty easily:

```
  /* creating a months table */

create table dbo.Months([Month] date primary key, MonthEnd date);

declare @StartDate     date = '20100101'
       ,@NumberOfYears int  = 30;

insert dbo.Months([Month],MonthEnd)
  select top (12*@NumberOfYears) 
      [Month] = dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @StartDate)
      , MonthEnd = dateadd(day,-1,
            dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number), @StartDate)
            )
    from master.dbo.spt_values;

    /* the query */

select [Month], [Count]=count(*)
  from dbo.Months mo
    inner join dbo.[Membership] me on 
    /* Member since the start of the month */
            me.MemberFromDate >= mo.[Month]  
    /* Member for the entire month being counted */
        and me.MemberToDate   > mo.[MonthEnd] 
  group by [Month]
  order by [Month]
```

If you really don't want to have a Months table, you can use a `cte` like this:

```
declare @StartDate     date = '20100101'
       ,@NumberOfYears int  = 30;

;with Months as (
select top (12*@NumberOfYears) 
    [Month] = dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @StartDate)
    , MonthEnd = dateadd(day,-1,
          dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number), @StartDate)
          )
  from master.dbo.spt_values
)

    /* the query */

select [Month], [Count]=count(*)
  from Months mo
    inner join dbo.[Membership] me on 
    /* Member since the start of the month */
            me.MemberFromDate >= mo.[Month]  
    /* Member for the entire month being counted */
        and me.MemberToDate   > mo.[MonthEnd] 
  group by [Month]
  order by [Month]
```

Comment: Thank you, I found this easy to understand and have it doing what I wanted now.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table members(name varchar(50),fromdate datetime, todate datetime)
go
create table months(firstday datetime)
go
insert members values('Joe','2014-02-01','2015-03-25'),('Jon','2014-03-12','2015-01-12')

declare @date datetime = '2000-01-01'
while (@date < '2016-01-01')
begin
  insert into months values( @date )
  select @date = dateadd(month,1,@date)
end

with MyCTE(date) as
(   select left(convert(varchar, firstday, 120),7)
    from members m
    join months d on d.firstday > m.fromdate and d.firstday < datefromparts(year(m.todate),month(m.todate),1)
)
select date as 'month', count(*) as 'count'
from MyCTE
group by date
```